# Apply starter kit Umbraco7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, starter-kits

Migth sound silly but I just started with Umbraco and I am trying to apply a starter kit to my first test page, but I can't find how to do it. How can I apply a starter kit for Umbraco 7?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are installing Umbraco there is a link which says "Customize" next to some green button, can't remember exactly where (might be the bit where you type your login credentials in). Its easy to miss as you can be drawn to the button that says something along the lines of "GO".